# How About string datatype is stored as bytes

Tags: c++, string, sizeof, c-strings, string-literals

## Question

Hello!
My question is about string datatype value when it is stored as bytes.
See my code below:

## What's Problem

```
int main(){
    string name, names[6];
    std::cout<<sizeof(name)<<endl; //32 bytes
    std::cout<<sizeof "n"<<endl; //2 bytes
    std::cout<<sizeof "//n"<<endl; //3 bytes
    std::cout<<sizeof(names)<<endl; //192 bytes
}
```

## Any Explaination?

Why is this happening? Can someone explain me how string datatype stores itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the output of this statement

```
std::cout<<sizeof "//n"<<endl; //3 bytes
```

is `4`.

In this statement

```
std::cout<<sizeof(name)<<endl;
```

there is outputted the size of an object of the type `std::string`. It is not the size of a string stored in the object. To output the size of the string you should write

```
std::cout<<name.size()<<endl;
```

and you will get `0` because the object does not contain any string.

So if the size of an object of the type std::string is equal to 32 then the size of an array that contains 6 such objects is `6 * 32 = 192`.

In this statement

```
std::cout<<sizeof "n"<<endl;
```

there is an output of the size of the string literal `"n"` that contains 2 characters (`{ 'n', '\0' }`) including the terminating zero.

And in this statement

```
std::cout<<sizeof "//n"<<endl;
```

there is also an output of the size of the string literal `"//n"` that contains 4 characters including the terminating zero.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a `std::string` object is nothing more than a pointer to the actual string data<sup>1</sup>, and some information about the string it wraps (like its current length). There might be other implementation-specific data that pushes up this number.

And to understand the size of string literals like `"n"`, you need to understand that all string literals in C++ are really arrays of constant characters, *including* the string null-terminator character. So e.g. `"n"` is really an array of two characters: The `'n'` character and the `'\0'` string terminator.

That means your claim that `sizeof "//n"` is three bytes is wrong, it's really four bytes.

Finally, the size of an array is the total size of the array. In other words the size of each element multiplied by the number of elements.

---

<sup>1</sup> While this is the "classic" view of `std::string`, it's not always true as there's often something called *short string optimization* where short string can be fully stored inside the `std::string` object itself. There's no standardized limit that defines a "short string", and it's really an implementation detail.